# OnClickListener and changing TextView

Tags: android

I have fragment with ListView. I set onClickListener on the button, and when the button is clicked, one text view in listview element change for example from "0" to "1". But nothing happens, have I refresh fragment or something else to see diference?

Comment: Post your code what you tried..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) from your adapter to reflect any changes in the listview adapter.

> public void notifyDataSetChanged () Added in API level 1
>
> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been
>   changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.